# add a digit Into Existing Column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

hi im trying to add a digit to a SQL row using this code:

```
SELECT

      RIGHT( '0900000000' + LTRIM( RTRIM( [Leading_Zero_Field_Name] ) ), 10 )

FROM

      [Table_Name]
```

in the row numbers are formatted with 9 digts like this:

```
098928000
097652183
098037207
```

what i want to accomplish is to add an extra 9 after the first 0 it should be a total of 10 digits and should look like this:

```
0998928000
0997652183
0998037207
```

now the problem is when i apply the code above like this:

```
UPDATE

      [Table_Name]

SET

      [Leading_Zero_Field_Name] = RIGHT( '0900000000' + LTRIM( RTRIM( [Leading_Zero_Field_Name] ) ), 10 )
```

i get this result:

```
998928000
997652183
998037207
```

i don't know why the query deletes the first 0 btw i the type of the row is VARCHAR i also tried with TEXT with the same result.

Comment: are you sure you are getting 9 digits with `Right(...,10)`?

Comment: yes, that's the problem the query ignores the zero at the beginning

Comment: You tagged this with MySQL though your syntax is for SQL Server (those dreaded `[]` brackets). Which one are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RIGHT function uses as many characters from the 1st argument as needed. Your existing numbers don't need that many, just a few so change:

```
RIGHT( '0900000000' + LTRIM( RTRIM( [Leading_Zero_Field_Name] ) ), 10 )
```

TO

```
SELECT RIGHT( '09' + LTRIM( RTRIM( Leading_Zero_Field_Name) ), 10 )
```

**Edited:** Using your input provided:

```
SELECT RIGHT( '09' + LTRIM( RTRIM( 098928000) ), 10 )
```

Results

```
0998928000
```

Does your input change in length?

Comment: what's the problem now? what's the output?

Comment: `98928009
97652192
98037216` bad output

Comment: I took your input example, ran it using the select statement and gave me exactly the output you are looking for. See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server has this function called [`STUFF()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx). It lets you, among other things, insert a string into another string at a specific position.

In your case, returning results with a `9` inserted at the 2nd position of every value would look like this:

```
SELECT STUFF(ColumnName, 2, 0, '9') AS NewValue
FROM TableName;
```

If you really want a MySQL solution, as the tags seem to suggest, use the [`INSERT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_insert) function, whose set of parameters is identical to that of `STUFF()`.